# Allow a Jenkins user to assign roles to others

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there a way in Jenkins to grant a **non-administrator** user the permission to **assign roles to other users**?

I'm using the [Role Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) and would like to create a role to allow a slightly privileged user to assign project roles to others. The problem is that the screen to do this is found at `Manage Jenkins>Manage and Assign Roles>Assign Roles` and to get there a user must have the `Jenkins.ADMINISTER` permission -a.k.a. `Overall Administer`.

I'm wondering if there's any way to get more fine-grained administration permissions defined.

Comment: Just to clarify, I know there's no out-of-the-box way to do this. I posted this question to get some guidance on what options I can explore to achieve this. Maybe someone knows of a plugin that breaks admin down into more fine grained permissions? Or a plugin for an alternate admin console? Or maybe someone could tell me how should I go about customizing the admin console? I'm open to all ideas.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option from the Role Strategy Plugin. Jenkins also having 3 defined roles - anonymous, authenticated-user, administrator.

All the activities related to Jenkins(Instance) configuration can be modified by a person who has administer privileges.

Comment: Hi @Suresh, please have a look at my comment above on the question. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I already experienced same requirement and left it, as I can't achieve this because of the Jenkins design. So that's the reason concluded there is no out of box solution.

Comment: As you are open to ideas, recently a new feature has been released in Version 2.5.0 Role Strategy Plugin. You can add a page or you can create a application to add/modify/delete roles and permissions using Rest Api. Please go through the [wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) page for more information.